# How can I make Distribution Build withOut ios device?

Tags: ios, app-store

Now I have not any ios device(iphone), but I finish my app and I want to publish it to appStore. How can I do what if xCode have empty devices table?

I got distribution certificate and I stopped on import provision in xcode

Comment: select ios Device and go for archive and rest all u know .its doesnot depend on that u have to device connected .Just select the iOS device from list and go on

Comment: I have no iphone now, do I need iphone or ipad?

Comment: No not necessary.You do not need an iOS device to distribute an application

Comment: Keep in mind that you really should test you app on a real device (possibly more than one) before releasing your app. Simulator is a great tool but you might not detect all the bugs and possible crashes without testing on real device(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need an iOS device to distribute an application. Select iOS Device from the device menu, and then your distribution profiles in project settings. Under Product menu, select archive. When archiving is finished, by following the new window you can submit your app.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here[image]

Select the IOS Device ..
Then `clean& Build` then `Product-->Archive`

Comment: I have no iphone now, do I need iphone or ipad?

Comment: No need at all . Just follow the procedure by selecting the IOS Device .yourself will come  to know

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of any real device for preparing the distribution build, just set the active device as ios device and select Product-->archive then select distribute in organizer then select submit to app store.

Selecting IOS Device in active device will let the Xcode build the app for armv7 architecture instead of i386 architecture.